# IOS: remove a subview with cancelButtonTitel of UIAlert

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uialertview, cancel-button

Can I remove a subview with cancelButtonTitle of a UIAlert? Because I write this:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done!" 
                                                    message:[@"It's all ok!"]
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but this code remove my subview before I push cancelButtonTitle, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, implement the UIAlertViewDelegate method `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` and dismiss your view there.

Set the delegate to self first:

```
...
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done!" 
                                                    message:[@"It's all ok!"]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
...
```

Could look like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Protip: use `if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex])` if you are unsure about the cancelButtonIndex :-)

Comment: But I must call this method...no? [self alertView:alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:?????]; what I must write in clickedButtonAtIndex???

Comment: @fluchtpunkt thanks, I was always using my own constants for that

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate of the `UIAlertView` to self and implement:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

In this method, dismiss the view.